# Why is my SQL query not updating user properties other than 'user' in Node.js and MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js

I have a Service method to update a user from the database:

```
const updateUser = async (user) => {
    const {firstName, lastName, email, password, phone, dob, countryid, gender, address, role, id} = user;
    const sql = `UPDATE user set user_firstName = ?, user_lastName = ?, user_email = ?, user_password = ?, user_phoneNumber = ?, user_dob= ?, user_countryId = ?, user_gender = ?, user_address = ?, user_role= ? WHERE client_id = ?`;
    try {
        await db.query(sql, [firstName, lastName, email, password, phone, dob, countryid, gender, address, role, id]);
        return { message: "records updated successfully." }
    } catch (error) {
        return { message: "Failed to updated" }
    }
}
```

whenever I log user alone it can read it, but it's not reading any other properties ( firstName etc...) and getting this error: Bind parameters must not contain undefined. To pass SQL NULL specify JS null.

preview of `console.log(user)`:

[image]

my route is working perfectly, the same function has been used before without any issues

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. Are you using [tag:mysql], or [tag:sql-server]? Also, what have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: This is at least partially a typo-level problem. You're using `firstName` and `lastName` in your destructuring pattern, but the object doesn't have properties with those names. (It has `firstname` and `lastname` instead -- capitalization matters).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Separately, it's ***very*** insecure to store passwords in databases, **especially** *plain text* passwords as in the above. Instead, store hashes using a well-tested, battle-hardened hashing algorithm like [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (e.g., SHA-256, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user` argument you're printing out isn't an object representing a user, it's an array with a single such element. In addition, the object itself doesn't have the `firstName` and `lastName` properties you're trying to use, it has `firstname` and `lastname` (notice the lowercase `n`s). Since they aren't there, they get `undefined` values

Assuming you intended to pass an array to the function, you should probably iterate over all the users an update each of them. Regarding the properties, if you replace `firstName` and `lastName` with `firstname` and `lastname`, respectively, you should be OK:

```js
const updateUser = async (users) => {
    users.forEach(user => {
        const {firstname, lastname, email, password, phone, dob, countryid, gender, address, role, id} = user; // Here
        const sql = `UPDATE user set user_firstName = ?, user_lastName = ?, user_email = ?, user_password = ?, user_phoneNumber = ?, user_dob= ?, user_countryId = ?, user_gender = ?, user_address = ?, user_role= ? WHERE client_id = ?`;
        try {
            await db.query(sql, [firstname, lastname, email, password, phone, dob, countryid, gender, address, role, id]); // And here!
            return { message: "records updated successfully." }
        } catch (error) {
            return { message: "Failed to updated" }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah just realized about this, but still giving me the same error, whenever i try to log firstname ( double checked for any typo) still giving me undefined.

Comment: @Anth missed the fact it's an array - see my edited answer.